# Parallax escrolling effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

I want to do exactly the same as this page. http://www.googleventures.com/

It is like a parallax effect when you slide down the lower part of the page comes up. How can I do that with an image as a header? Pure jquery? Is there an onSlide function?

Comment: Parallax? That just looks like regular scrolling except that one part is fixed in its position and has a lower z-index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did an alternate option.  You don't even need z-index, since the newer elements are automatically higher in z-index.

**HTML**

```
<div class="fixed">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/800/300" />
  This is some text that will be static as well
</div>
<div class="scroll">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
.fixed{
    position: fixed;
}
.scroll{
    background: #eee;
    height: 700px;
    position: relative;
    top: 350px;        
}​
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/3vxBA/

Answer (score 3):

That just looks like the header has a fixed position and a lower z-index, so when you scroll regularly, the page continues upward but the header stays in the same position behind the main contents.

Sample HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="header">
some image here
</div>

<div id="pagecontent">
everything else
</div>

</body>​
```

Sample CSS:

```
body {
    padding-top: 100px; /* #header height */
}

#header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: #ccccff;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}

#pagecontent {
    background-color: #ccffcc;
    height: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
}​
```

Here's this as a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Nv7Ku/

Comment: this works perfect! How does the z-index work? what if I put an smaller number, let say -2O?

Comment: @a.litis In this example, making it more negative won't do anything differently unless you have other items that also have custom z-indexes. Z-index sets visual order of elements, lowest to highest. Default is 0; a z-index smaller than 0 will be rendered "behind" or "underneath" the normal layer; a higher z-index will be rendered "in front" or "on top". You can give a bunch of elements different z-indexes to have them appear in a certain visual order. [These Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Understanding_z-index) offer a better explanation and some good examples.